# CLion Mac EOF Possible Bug

Tags: c, clion, eof

I have written a simple input line counter code and trying to run it on CLion but when I try to put `EOF` with `CMD + D`(from the CLion Keymap) program ends without either errors or results. However, I can execute the same code via Terminal (`EOF` with `ctrl + d`) and run it properly. I have seen examples of this question but not a satisfying answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n1,c;
    n1 =0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c == '\n'){
            ++n1;
        }
    }
    printf("n1 : %d \n", n1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that Mac systems are a little special, but are you sure that the end-of-file keyboard sequence really is `CMD-D` and not the POSIX standard `Ctrl-D`?

Comment: On CLion Preferences -> Keymap shows me that EOF command is executed via `CMD + D`